# Metaboxes in Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I want to create metaboxes in foreach loop. The requirement is, I have an array of custom post types and I want to run a loop to add metaboxes for the post types that are as a key in an array. 
So far I have developed much of the requirement but now I am stuck in the part where callback function inside `add_meta_box()` is to be called. I have used `call_user_func_array` to call the callback function and pass the `$key` as an argument but it is returning error and its not working. Below is my code:

```
function rttk_create_boxes(){
    $myarray = $this->rttk_get_posttype_array();
    foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
        // echo "key--".$key;
        // $arr[] = '';
        // $arr[] = $key;
        $key = (array)$key;
        add_meta_box(
            'rttk_'.end($key).'_id',
            __( 'Details', 'rara-theme-toolkit-pro' ),
            //array($this,'rttk_testimonials_metabox_callback',$key),
            call_user_func_array(array( $this, 'rttk_testimonials_metabox_callback'),$key ),
            $key,
            'side',
            'high'
        );
    }
}

// testimonials template form
public function rttk_testimonials_metabox_callback($key){
        include RTTKPRO_BASE_PATH.'/includes/meta-parts/rttk-'.$key.'-template.php';
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use the callback in a class context, but I see no class declaration. Maybe it was left out, but here's a possible solution without using class.

```
function rttk_create_boxes() {
    $myarray = $this->rttk_get_posttype_array();
    foreach ( $myarray as $key => $value ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'rttk_' . $key . '_id',
            __( 'Details', 'rara-theme-toolkit-pro' ),
            'rttk_testimonials_metabox_callback',
            null,
            'side',
            'high',
            array( 'key' => $key )
        );
    }
}

// testimonials template form
function rttk_testimonials_metabox_callback( $post, $args ) {
    $key = $args['args']['key'];
    include RTTKPRO_BASE_PATH . '/includes/meta-parts/rttk-' . $key . '-template.php';
}
```